# Will a running program be killed if I suspend my OS?

Tags: process, power-management

I am running a program. If I suspend my OS (Ubuntu 12.04) in the middle, will the process of the running program be killed? If not, when I wake up my OS, how can I resume the process? Thanks!

Comment: That's kind of the whole point of suspend...

Comment: You won't have to do anything. The application will resume right from where it was when the system was put into suspend. Only network connections will have been lost.

Answer (score 4):

> If I suspend my OS (Ubuntu 12.04) in the middle, will the process of the running program be killed?

Generally no, but there are some exceptions to this, e.g., if `ssh` connections have timed out, those will die when you resume.

I've also occasionally noticed a weird one with a server process that uses `epoll()` on a non-blocking socket (don't know if that is relevent) getting killed by the kernel if the suspend happens at some odd moment during the poll.  Point being, it's not impossible for stuff like this to happen, but generally it is pretty seemless.

> when I wake up my OS, how can I resume the process?

Processes should resume along with the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Any open network connections will have timed out by the time you resume, leading to the programs in case often exiting or crashing. But note that e.g. the web browser really opens the network connection only to get or refresh the page(s), so it won't be directly affected.

Comment: "_Any_ open network connections will have timed out by the time you resume" are you sure about that?

Comment: If you resume soon enough, even the network connections will be still working.